# Python OOP - Why do I need modul name in Function

Tags: python, oop

I'm learning OOP in Python and I don't get why I've to put "turtle" into the definition of the function "draw()". The code runs also without the turtle (just "def draw(self)"...) - so why do I need to put it there - or what does it exactly do?

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, radius=50, color="transparent", \
        outline="black", edgeWidth=1):
        self.x = x
                (...)

    def draw(self, turtle):
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(self.x, self.y)
                (...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`turtle` is a module. It is defined in a global namespace, you'll be able to access it from anywhere (given that you correctly imported in your module): `import turtle`.

You don't need to pass it as arguments to any function (unless you're trying to do something else that you haven't specified in the question).

Even from an object oriented perspective, does it sounds well that a Circle object needs a `turtle` to be drawn? It sounds weird to me, a Circle object knows how to draw itself without additional arguments (given that in the constructor are already specified every data needed to be drawn of course).

Of course, maybe it can be helpful to specify a *target* where to draw the circle. In that case an additional parameter can make sense, something like `circle.draw(board)` (draw yourself on this board). But `board` here should be a wrapper for `turtle` or a *non sigleton drawable* object. In Python, `turtle` is a module and the `Screen` it uses is sigleton thus basically, everything you do on it (even on different circles) will draw to the same place.

Ok maybe, for the sake of completeness, *your textbook* meant this:

```
import turtle
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
```

Here, `t1` and `t2` are two different turtles. They are both gonna be drawn to the same screen, but they're independent from each other. In this case, it makes sense to have a `turtle` argument since you could do this:

```
c1 = Circle()
c2 = Circle()
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()

c1.draw(t1)  # draw yourself but with the turtle 1
c2.draw(t2)  # draw yourself but with the turtle 2
```

And you'll get to independent circles. In that case it makes a lot of sense and probably what the text meant.

The confusion arose because you named the argument `turtle` and call its functions from within the method with the name `turtle`, since `turtle` is also a module and is on the global namespace then you wondered whether this will be necessary. Now that you know both approaches you can select which one fits your needs :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: so i don't need it!? because that's what i thought ... but it was written in my textbook without explanation and so i thought that it maybe is something similar to the inheritance syntax used for classes ... & thanks for your help!

Comment: @Hans-WernerOhneSinn Read my last paragraph, there can be situations where you may need it, but is complicated to explain since `turtle` in Python is a module, not an instance of some class.

Comment: @Hans-WernerOhneSinn Added further explanation to the logic on your textbook. I hope is more clear now.